# TypeError: undefined is not a function while logOn to steam

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, steam

I am working on steam project. For that I am using node-steam module. I am stuct at login part.
I getting this exception while I am trying to logOn to steam account using node-steam
Exception as follow:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function   MYAPP/node_modules/adm-zip/zipFile.js:8 
Module.exports  /MYAPP/node_modules/adm-zip/zipFile.js:8 
module.exports /MYAPP/node_modules/adm-zip/adm-zip.js:25
handlers.(anonymous function) /MYAPP/node_modules/steam/lib/steam_client.js:252 
SteamClient._netMsg`enter code here`Received /MYAPP/node_modules/steam/lib/steam_client.js:157
emitOne events.js:75
emit events.js:150
Connection._readPacket /MYAPP/node_modules/steam/lib/connection.js:50
emitNone events.js:65
EMIT events.js:147
emitReadable__  _stream_readable.js:408  
emitReadable   _stream_readable.js:402
readableAddChunk _stream_readable.js:157
Readable.push _stream_readable.js:109
onread net.js:510
Error: Disconnected
at SteamClient._disconnected (/MYAPP/node_modules/steam/lib/steam_client.js:186:24)
at emitOne (events.js:75:13)
at Connection.emit (events.js:150:7)
at TCP.close (net.js:457:12)
```

My source code is add follow:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Steam = require('steam');
var crypto = require('crypto');

var serverlist = [] //server list here
Steam.servers = serverlist;

var steamClient = new Steam.SteamClient();
var steamUser = new Steam.SteamUser(steamClient);

steamClient.connect();

steamUser.on('updateMachineAuth', function (sentry, callback) {
    console.log('writing to file sentry');
    fs.writeFileSync('sentry', sentry.bytes);
    callback({ sha_file: getSHA1(sentry.bytes) });
});

function getSHA1(bytes) {
    var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');
    shasum.end(bytes);
    return shasum.read();
}

steamClient.on('connected', function () {    
    steamUser.logOn({
        account_name: “XXXXXXXX”,
        password: “XXXXXXXX”,
        // un-comment this when providing secondary auth-code from email
        auth_code: ‘XXX’,
        sha_sentryfile: getSHA1(fs.readFileSync('sentry'))
    });
});

steamUser.on('loggedOn', function () {
    console.log('Logged in!');
});


steamClient.on('debug', function (response) {
    console.log("debug: " + response);
});

steamClient.on('logOnResponse', function (response) {
    console.log(">>logOnResponse");
    console.log(response);

if (response.eresult == Steam.EResult.OK) {
    console.log('Logged in!');
    // Your code here
}

});

steamClient.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log(error.stack);
    alert("yes error");
});

steamClient.on('servers', function (servers) {
    alert(servers);
    // fs.writeFile('servers', JSON.stringify(servers));
});

steamClient.on('disconnected', function (s) {
    alert(s);
});
```

Below are my installed versions.

Node Version: v10.8.0
NPM Version: 6.4.1
Steam Version: 1.4.0
OS: Mac

Please help me to resolve this issue .

Comment: Could you validate my answer please?

Answer (score 0):

The error that is being yield, `undefined is not a function` is happening because you are calling the function `alert` in `node`

That is not valid, as in node there is no function that is called like that, and since you have that function also in the `errorHandler` then the application dies.

If you were to delete the function `alert` of if you created and "alert" function that would `console.log()` what is happening the error should dissapear.

Try adding this function to your code or delete all of the alert functions:

```
const alert = () => {
  console.log(arguments)
}
```